# rmr: Cannot delete /output. Name node is in safe mode

Tags: hadoop

1. In Hadoop2.6.0 I use command:

   ```
   ./bin/hadoop fs -rmr /output
   ```

   Then I got:

   ```
   rmr: Cannot delete /output. Name node is in safe mode.
   ```
2. I use command:

   ```
   hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
   ```

   to resolve this problem, and I got the result:

   ```
   Safe mode is OFF
   ```
3. But when I delete the file `/output`, I got the same error:

   ```
   rmr: Cannot delete /output. Name node is in safe mode.
   ```
4. I see following in the logs:

   > 2015-04-07 03:10:18,362 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: STATE* Safe mode is ON. Resources are low on NN.
   >
   > Please add or free up more resources then turn off safe mode manually.
   >
   > NOTE:  If you turn off safe mode before adding resources, the NN will immediately return to safe mode.
   >
   > Use "hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave" to turn safe mode off.

How Can I handle this problem?

Comment: If you are using a single node cluster and get this error, check if `datanode` is online and how much free space you are having by typing this `df -h` in terminal. If you get the error in multiple node cluster, you need to check if all the `datanodes are online` (free disk space if necessary).

Comment: This may be due to low disk space or else problem with datanode.

Comment: I am using a single node cluster.`datanode`is online.I thought it's because of the low disk space.Only 42M Available.And How can i **free the space**?PS: after I use the command `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`the safemode is still **on**.

Comment: Delete the contents in `/tmp` folder. It may free up some space.

Comment: I remove all of the data and name file.so all information of the project disappear.And I reformat the namenode.