# Error in creating database in Hive

Tags: hive

Command

```
create database IF NOT EXISTS emp;
```

Error

```
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot create directory /user/hive/warehouse/emp.db. Name node is in safe mode.
The ratio of reported blocks 0.9091 has not reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2055)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:2029)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.mkdirs(NameNode.java:817)
```

Comment: run # sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave and recreate ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting fs.default.name in core-site.xml Sets HDFS to Safemode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412328/setting-fs-default-name-in-core-site-xml-sets-hdfs-to-safemode)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your namenode is in safe mode.

If your cluster don't have enough space in datanode to store data, namenode may goes to safemode.

When namenode is in safemode, you cannot do any write operation on the cluster. During safemode, HDFS cluster is in read only mode and doesn't allow any changes to the file system.

To leave from safemode, run

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

Similar questions

[Name node is in safe mode. Not able to leave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803266/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-not-able-to-leave)

[Name node is in safe mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027445/name-node-is-in-safe-mode)

[rmr: Cannot delete /output. Name node is in safe mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489822/rmr-cannot-delete-output-name-node-is-in-safe-mode)

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Solved your problem?